# Flutter - restrict widget to match others widget height

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I would like to create list item widget with photo, and some information on the right side of this photo. Since web Image may be way to large, I also want my photo widget to match the height (while maintaining aspect ration) with "content" widgets height, possibly without giving an explicit height. 
For now my widget looks like this:

[image: item]

In Android I would restrict image size with:
constraintTop_toTopOf(contentId)
constraintBottom_toBottomOf(contentId)

Is it possible to do similar thing in Flutter ?
For now my code looks like this (I would like to avoid giving explicit height in 'maxHeight' parameter of ConstrainedBox):

```
class SpeakerItemWidget extends StatelessWidget{

  final Speaker _speaker;

  SpeakerItemWidget(this._speaker);

  Widget _speakerItemContent() =>
      Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            '${_speaker.name} ${_speaker.surname}',
            style: TitleTextStyle(),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: Margin.small),
          Text(
            _speaker.title,
            style: DescriptionTextStyle(),
          ),
          Text(
            _speaker.company,
            style: DescriptionTextStyle(),
          )
        ],
      );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) =>
      InkWell(
        splashColor: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
        onTap: () => debugPrint('open event details'),
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(Margin.small),
          child: ConstrainedBox(
            constraints: BoxConstraints(
              maxHeight: 60,
            ),
            child: Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                FittedBox(
                  fit: BoxFit.contain,
                  child: SpeakerPhotoWidget(_speaker),
                ),
                _speakerItemContent(),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
}
```

```
class SpeakerPhotoWidget extends StatelessWidget{

  final Speaker _speaker;

  SpeakerPhotoWidget(this._speaker);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return  ConstrainedBox(
      constraints: BoxConstraints(
        //initial size of widget is 0,0 - causes crash when inside FittedBox
        minHeight: 1,
        minWidth: 1,
      ),
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: Margin.small),
        child: FadeInImage.assetNetwork(
          placeholder: 'assets/images/speaker_placeholder.png',
          image: 'some uri',
          fit: BoxFit.contain,
        ),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: if I have to get the desired layout - I would use - `ListTile`widget.`ListTile(
      leading: CircleAvatar(
        maxRadius: 30.0,
        backgroundImage: NetworkImage('https://placeimg.com/640/480/any'),
      ),
      title: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8.0,right: 8.0),
        child: Text('john Doe'),
      ),
      subtitle: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text('Manager'),
          Text('Company name'),
        ],
      ),
    )`

Comment: Look into [IntrinsicHeight](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/IntrinsicHeight-class.html) maybe it helps you.